# Binarizing Data in a Network using the sign function

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I often see the use of the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function in machine learning models as a way to binarize data (see eqn 1 [here](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Cakir_Adaptive_Hashing_for_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf) for an example). But the derivative of the sign function is the [dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions), so backpropagating through the network will yield either 0 or infinity? I'm confused as to **why it makes any sense to still use it**?

A more concrete example:

Consider a network where each node in a hidden layer $n_i$ measures whether the current training point $x$ is within distance $d_i$ from some anchor point $a_i$. This can be represented as $sign(||x-a_i||_2 - d_i)$. This is a rudimentary example of a locality preserving embedding network. Naturally, the loss function will depend on the result of this node in some way. Thereofre when I try to compute the partial derivate of the loss function with respec to $a_i$ or $d_i$, it will result in a gradient of 0 and learning will not be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a significant neural net application anywhere using the *sign* function as neuron activation because of the *non-differentiable* nature of it as you've noted down. In the paper you cited, I couldn't see a direct connection to neural-nets however as you say, they use SGD, but also note that (in Page 3) "*we approximate the non-differentiable sgn function with the sigmoid*". So, they actually approximate the *sign* function, so its derivative.

Comment: Very true! Thank's for your help